# button to open a chatbot from a modal not working in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, modal-dialog, queryselector

So, i've been trying to open a chatbot on the click of a button in a modal component. The button works alright in the home page but wouldn't work from the modal. Here's my code below. #nextJs #React
I'd appreciate any help ! Thanks.

Other approaches that failed:
i tried useRef to read the button click from the modal but it doesnt work.

I also tried attaching and calling the querySelector from the modal using useEffect but it keeps popping up an error not recognizing the querySelector even after defining the document/windows.
I've tried calling it via a function from onClick and still it doesnt work and even while the chatbot is showing it doesn't open.

I've also noticed that when i close the modal, the link to opening the chatbot from home page stops working.
I followed the initial tutorial from https://codepen.io/dominiczaq/pen/ajBQVQ?css-preprocessor=postcss

```
./pages/home.js

function home(props,{selector}) {
    useEffect(() => {
     (function() {
            function onTidioChatApiReady() {
              window.tidioChatApi.hide();
            }
          
            if (window.tidioChatApi) {
              window.tidioChatApi.on("ready", onTidioChatApiReady);
            }
          
            document.querySelectorAll(".chat-button").forEach(button=>{
               button.addEventListener("click", function() {
              window.tidioChatApi.show();
              window.tidioChatApi.open();
            })
        });
        })();
    }, [])

 return (
          <>
          <section>
         
           <button class="chat-button">
            Open Chat
           //this button works
           </button>
      
           </section>

          <section>

          <div class="inline-block px-10">
           
            <Modal />
                           
          </div>

           </section>
          </>
          );
          }

export default home;
```

```
./src/components/modal.js

         export default function Modal ({props, }){
            
           const [open, setOpen] = useState();
          
          return (
  
          <button type="button"  onClick={(e) => {setOpen(true);  } } class="w-64 h-64"}
          <img  src="https://www.aSampleImage.com" class="w-full h-full" />
          </button>
          { open && 
           <div className="backdrop" selector="#modal">

           <button>
           <h1 className="chat-button m-1"> 
           Open Chat  
           // this doesn't work , HELP !
           </h1>
           </button>

           <button onClick={() => setOpen(false)} className="btn-right submit btn modal-close close" type="button" >
            <CloseIcon className="m-1"/>
           </button>

           </div>
           }
           )
           }
```

Please note that the code i've posted here is redacted and my imports are alright. Also, i imported my script in _document.js since i'm using NextJs. see below.

```
./pages/_document.js

class MyDocument extends Document {
    render() {
        return (
            <Html lang="en">
            <Head> 
                <meta property="custom" content="" />          
            </Head>

            <body>
                <Main/>
            <script async src="//code.tidio.co/xxxxxMyChatBotAPIlinkxxxxxxx.js" strategy="lazyOnload" />
            </body>
            <NextScript/>
          
        </Html>
        );
    }
}

export default MyDocument;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working because

```
document.querySelectorAll(".chat-button")
```

can not select your open chat button in modal because it's not exist in DOM when modal is closed. So you can create a open function and pass to your button

```
export default function Modal ({ props }){
        
const [open, setOpen] = useState();

const openChat = () => {
    tidioChatApi?.show();
    tidioChatApi?.open();
}

return (
    <button type="button"  onClick={(e) => setOpen(true)} class="w-64 h-64">
        <img  src="https://www.aSampleImage.com" class="w-full h-full" />
    </button>
    {open && 
    <div className="backdrop" selector="#modal">
        <button onClick={openChat}>
            <h1 className="chat-button m-1"> 
                Open Chat
            </h1>
        </button>
    </div>}
)}
```

./pages/_document.js

```
class MyDocument extends Document {
render() {
    return (
        <Html lang="en">
        <Head> 
            <meta property="custom" content="" />
            <script async src="//code.tidio.co/xxxxxMyChatBotAPIlinkxxxxxxx.js" />
        </Head>

        <body>
            <Main/>
        </body>
        <NextScript/>
      
    </Html>
    );
}}

export default MyDocument;
```

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work. I've actually tried that approach calling it in an onClick function before but the button does nothing.   I've also noticed that when i close the modal, the link to opening the chatbot from home page stops working.

Comment: @Akeymann I create a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-wescoff-hx7c3?file=/pages/index.js) and it works, can you put script tag of chatbot inside Head component in _document.js

Comment: thanks ! It works now but the issue was not from the function. I noticed something you added to the top of your _document.js file                                      ` static async getInitialProps(ctx) { const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx); return { ...initialProps }; }  `         This was what i added and that did the trick, it started working. I really don't know how what that function does, i'd love to hear your explanation but that was it !!